# I want to print the number"10" which is given. While run this code, its automating properly but didnot given any result in eclipse

Tags: selenium-webdriver

WebElement we1 = driver.findElement(By.id("qty"));    we1.sendKeys("10");     Thread.sleep(2000);    String str1 = we1.getText();    System.out.println(str1);

Comment: But you are plussing two elements, not two integer values? Include html structure you are finding elements in, then its easy to fix :)

Comment: This code makes no sense... what are you trying to do?